# IntelliJ: activate Maven profile when running Junit tests

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have declared some properties that are specific to Maven profiles. A part of my pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>release</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <my.properties.file>foo.xml</my.properties.file>
                </properties>
            </profile>
            <profile>
              <id>ci</id>
              <properties>
                <my.properties.file>bar.xml</my.properties.file>
              </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

I encounter some problem to use the "ci" Maven profile when I start Junit tests via IntelliJ IDEA 2016.
I activate my profile via the "Maven Projects" panel, then I start tests. The problem is the "my.properties.file" property value is equal to "foo.xml", not "bar.xml".

I have no problem with command-line (I can use the "-Pci" flag). How can I tell IntelliJ to use the "ci" profile? Thx.

Comment: In the Maven Projects panel, when you open up Profiles in the tree view, does the profile you want show up with or without a checkbox?  Can you turn it on and off with the checkbox?  If not, then the profile is probably bound to something in the environment, like a property value.

Comment: @HankD the problem is not in profile, but in the fact that when run with IDE tests completely ignore active profile (which is sensible and probably can not be overridden)

Answer (score 2):

You should add the profiles to the Maven setting.xml file (you should find it in the path ${YOUR_MAVEN_HOME}\apache-maven-3.1.1\conf\setting.xml).
Then, you have to open intellij, click on View > Tool Windows > Maven Projects. There, you should see your profiles (ci and release) and select the correct one.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I added active profiles to the settings.xml, they appeared automatically activated in the Maven Projects panel, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can also configure a maven test in Intellij if you click on Run > Edit Configurations... > "+" Icon > select Maven and configure all the params. There you should specify the profile or profiles that you want to use

Comment: Yes, it works but I loose some IntelliJ integration. Per example I can't easily run a single test class/method, rerun failed tests, start debugger on tests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just finally solved it.

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile-to-be-activated-on-build</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault><!-- on your flavor -->
            <property>
                <name>mvn-profile-env-var-trigger</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
```

Goto JUnit default profile (aka configuration template). Add into JVM args:

```
-Dmvn-profile-env-var-trigger
```

You may need to manually reload maven profiles in IDE.

Also make sure on [Settings > Build Tools > Maven > Running tests] envVars is checked (or better everything).